# Pass dictionary key as parameter to a function python

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary and i have a use case where i need to update a certain key in the nested dictionary by passing it into a function. See the below code for example:

```
sample_dict = {
    'a':{'b':{'c':"Bye"},'f':{'d':"Tata"}},'g':{'e':"SeeYou"}
}

def value_modifier(key,new_value):
    key = new_value
    
value_modifier(sample_dict['a']['b']['c'],new_value="Hi")
# here i know i am not passing the key but its value

print(sample_dict) # this prints the original sample_dict

# but i want my dict as below after my desired operation: 
{
    'a':{'b':{'c':"Hi"},'f':{'d':"Tata"}},'g':{'e':"SeeYou"}
}
```

I also looked for solution using memory address,etc as well but i am not able to update my sample_dict's desired key's value.

Comment: Do you have control over the value modifier function?

Comment: Why won't just `sample_dict['a']['b']['c'] = "Hi"` work?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman, it is a MRE so I would assume there's a good reason for it (I can't see it either though :^)).

Answer (score 3):

You may pass 2 arguments to your function:

```
sample_dict = {
    'a':{'b':{'c':"Bye"},'f':{'d':"Tata"}},'g':{'e':"SeeYou"}
}

def value_modifier(parent, key, new_value):
    parent[key] = new_value
    
value_modifier(sample_dict['a']['b'], 'c', new_value="Hi")

print(sample_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could directly assign the value instead of calling a function:

```
sample_dict['a']['b']['c'] = "Hi"
```

but i'm guessing your function needs to be a bit more sophisticated.

you could make it resursive and add missing intermediate keys as needed:

```
def value_modifier(D,key,*moreKeys,new_value):
    if moreKeys:
        value_modifier(D.setdefault(key,{}),*moreKeys,new_value=new_value)
    else:
        D[key] = new_value
```

output:

```
sample_dict = {
    'a':{'b':{'c':"Bye"},'f':{'d':"Tata"}},'g':{'e':"SeeYou"}
}

value_modifier(sample_dict,'a','b','c',new_value="Hi")

print(sample_dict)

{'a': {'b': {'c': 'Hi'}, 'f': {'d': 'Tata'}}, 'g': {'e': 'SeeYou'}}
```

Comment: I quite like this though I think I would be tempted to accept a list of keys or a string with a well know separator and have the method unpack that.